# Bash program which is executed on child process of Node.js not show echo

Tags: node.js, bash, git

## Background

I'm working on node.js + react project.

I'm making automated deploy system on my ubuntu server which have my source.

So, I made webhook.js server and deploy.sh file.

webhook.js is for listening a message sended by github's webhook when I push some new commit and executing a deploy.sh bash program.

deploy.sh does `git pull origin master` and restart my server.

**webhook.js**

```
const secret = 'xxxxxxxx';

let http = require('http');
let crypto = require('crypto');

const exec = require('child_process').exec;

http.createServer(function(req, res){
  req.on('data', function(chunk){
    let sig = "sha1=" + crypto.createHmac('sha1', secret).update(chunk.toString()).digest('hex');

    if (req.headers['x-hub-signature'] == sig) {
      deploy(res);
    } else {
      console.log('un matched');
    }
  });
  res.end();
}).listen(8080);

function deploy(res){
  exec('/home/rpf5573/nodewebhook/deploy.sh', function(err, stdout, stderr){
    console.log('deploy.sh is called');
    if (err) {
      console.error(err);
      res.writeHead(404);
      return res.end();
    }
    res.writeHead(200);
    res.end();
  });
}
```

**deploy.sh**

```
cd /home/rpf5573/react-discovery-v2

echo "Pulling from Master" 

git pull origin master

echo "Pulled successfully from master"

echo "Restarting server..."

npm restart-server

echo "Server restarted Successfully"
```

## So, what's your problem?

my deploy.sh dosent show any `echo` message. `git pull origin master`is executed well, but only echo message not work !

How can I see the echo message?

Is this because deploy.sh is executed other shell?

Comment: You're not doing anything with the stdout or stderr results. Where do you expect them to be displayed?

Comment: Tangentially, diagnostic output should be sent to stderr, not stdout (`echo "$0: message here" >&2`)

Comment: Which command do you actually manually run in your terminal?

Comment: @tripleee I want to see that message on my terminal. what is `$0 and >&2` ???

Comment: @l0b0 I just run `node webhook.js` command manually and listening message from github webhook. And my child process will run deploy.sh program. Do I understand your question well?